# C++ Html Parser as .NET HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c++, dom, html-parsing, html-parser

I'm porting my application over to C++ from C# and I need a library which can parse HTML and read html elements+their attributes and such, basicly everything that HtmlAgility pack has in C#.

I don't want to use HtmlAgilityPack or any other .NET inside my C++ application.

So could anyone suggest a good Html parser for C++? Speed is important factor.